# Jenkins-Github integration- Adhoc Error - ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, github, devops

All,

This is one of the error for me as nightmare, since this is completely adhoc and dont know why this error is coming and why its getting resolved by itself.

Basically, i am trying build a job which pull the code from the githib repo. This works most of the time but sometimes all of sudden i get the below error in Jenkins.

ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --no-tags --progress https://github.com/rammetla/LouisvilleOutletCode.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:
stdout:

And i have referred n number of posts for soluation but none of them appeared to be a right one for me.

Also, in the jenkins job, under git section i see the below message in highlighted red color.

Failed to connect to repository : Command "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe ls-remote -h https://github.com/rammetla/LouisvilleOutletCode.git HEAD" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr:

Please suggest a solution once for all.

Your help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One possible (not solution but) *workaround* would be to:

- use an SSH URL instead
- use the [JENKINS SSH Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Credentials+Plugin)

That would avoid any HTTPS credential issue, and its [related credential helper](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) which might at time cache the incorrect ones.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you help in bit details what do you mean bu Jenkins SSH Credentials plugin? How to add it? I tried installing "SSH" plugin Then go to manage jenkins--> Configure System --> Scroll down to SSH Host Connection section.. here i was asked to enter port name ,host name credentials etc..dont know what to enter your help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: @RamdasMetla For more information on how to create and use credentials in general in Jenkins, https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin. Make sure you have both installed.